# How can I check that .NET Framework 4.0 is installed on a computer via an Inno script used to deploy software on that computer?

Tags: .net, frameworks, inno-setup

I've read the previous post on this topic:

[Inno Setup: Verify that .NET 4.0 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104011/innosetup-how-to-check-the-framework-4-0)

and have tried using the suggested code in my script. I've made some modifications for testing purposes, but nothing that I believe is substantial:

```
[Code]
function IsDotNetDetected(version: string; service: cardinal): boolean;
// Indicates whether .NET Framework 4.0 is installed
// Taken from www.kynosarges.de/DotNetVersion.html
var
  key: string;
  install, serviceCount: cardinal;
  success: boolean;
begin
  key := 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\' + version;
  if Pos('v4', version) = 1 then begin
    success := success and RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'Servicing', serviceCount);
  end else begin
    success := success and RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'SP', serviceCount);
  end;
  result := success and (install = 1) and (serviceCount >= service);
end;

function InitalizeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  if not IsDotNetDetected('v4\Full', 0) then begin
    MsgBox('AppName requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Full Profile.'#13#13
        'Please download this from www.zemax.com/updates,'#13
        'and then re-run the AppName setup program.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    result := false;
  end else begin
    MsgBox('Found Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    result := true;
  end;
end;
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, and I cannot figure out why. When I compile the script, almost always the compilation hangs on the section of my script containing the code (above). If the script compilation is completed, and I begin to deploy the software, I never see a message box indicating either the presence or lack thereof of .NET Framework 4.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, and this should really go in the PrepareToInstall() event function.

Answer (score 2):

you have a Typo, the function name must be `InitializeSetup` instead of InitalizeSetup.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this bone-headed mistake! All seems to be well now.