# Install vcredist_x64.exe on install of VS 2015 installer Project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer

I have a msi installer project in VS 2015, and I have MSI dependency on vcredist_x64.exe (Redistributable package 2015). I am trying to install the pre-requiste with launch condition in installer project. But somehow the launch condition is always turning to be true so every time I click the installer it shows dialog to install vcredist_x64.exe every time even if its installed. The launch condition for windows installer project is as below snap 
[image]

and the launch condition is like below 
[image]

Can anyone help that kind of condition can be applied So that it installs prerequisite only if its unavailable[image].

I have also tried adding with custom actions but that also does not work well and shows error as both MSI installer output exe and vcredist_x64.exe runs at same time, and any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the Prerequisites button on the Properties of the setup project. The x64 redist is one of the choices that the setup.exe will install before running your MSI. It needs to be this way because it's MSI-based and you can't run recursive MSI installs, so you can't install it from your custom action, as you've discovered.

Can you provide a reference for the ComponentID you're using for that search? I have that runtime installed but that component id is not installed on my system.

Try one of these component ids from an inventory of my system, ids and descriptions. The minimum runtimes are the basic required ones, I assume:

{22824972-0C4A-31B4-AEEF-9FC7596F1305} 
     Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.23506
     C:\Windows\system32\msvcp140.dll

{35B5C1D2-EB5B-3569-83EB-78E34F5C3254} :
     Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.23506 
     C:\Windows\system32\concrt140.dll

{F5E98D96-3C7F-37D7-821F-E4BB03D4384B} 
     Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.23506
     C:\Windows\system32\vcomp140.dll

{B33258FD-750C-3B42-8BE4-535B48E97DB4}
     Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.23506 
     C:\Windows\system32\vcruntime140.dll

{7050289E-BECF-32C7-89DC-08C4480E482B}
     Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.23506
     C:\Windows\system32\vcamp140.dll

{D227D7DF-D9F8-33AF-B935-4BF2F47F2EA4}
     Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.23506 
     C:\Windows\system32\vccorlib140.dll

Comment: The Component ID I used is for Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable 14.0.23026 (  VC_2015_REDIST_X64_MIN) version which I got from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35160846/install-vcredist-x64-exe-on-install-of-vs-2015-installer-project/35161977#35161977

Comment: On Trying to install dependency from Prerequistes with download location URL which is https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145  as you suggested I see installation dialog but it fails to install with error regarding exe changed since it was initially published temp location.

Comment: For finding component ID I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137424/how-to-make-vcredist-x86-reinstall-only-if-not-yet-installed  as reference

Comment: Those guids are for older versions as far as I can tell. The ids will change for every C__ runtime release because they are different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and finally I am using Prerequistes with "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application" option to install. This solved the issue for me.