# Inno Setup script not install. Displays error: "Internal error: .Net Framework not found"

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

Can anyone shed light on this Inno Setup error that one of my users is getting?

[image]

He can install the same software on another computer with no issues. I asked him to supply me with his log file (the installer copies the log to a specific folder with a timestamp in the `CurStepChange` procedure (when the `CurStep = ssDone`).

But he could not find any log. I have now asked him to run the installer from a Command Prompt with the `/log="..."` switch to see if we can get at the log that way.

His computer is running Windows 11 (this is also my development PC operating system).

Any ideas?

---

Note that the installer does check for the existing of the Framework in the `InitializeWizard` procedure:

```
dotNetNeeded := not IsDotNetInstalled(net462, 0);
if (dotNetNeeded) then begin
    if (MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:DotNet_NeedToDownload}'), \
                                        mbConfirmation, MB_OKCANCEL) = IDCANCEL) then begin
        Abort();
    end;
end;
```

---

#### Update

I am no Delphi developer, but I thought I would check the public source code for Inno Setup and I found two places where this error is displayed:

```
function GetDotNetInstallRoot(const RegView: TRegView): String;
var
  K: HKEY;
begin
  if DotNetRoot[RegView] = '' then begin
    if RegOpenKeyExView(RegView, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework', 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, K) = ERROR_SUCCESS then begin
      RegQueryStringValue(K, 'InstallRoot', DotNetRoot[RegView]);
      RegCloseKey(K);
    end;
    if DotNetRoot[RegView] = '' then
      InternalError('.NET Framework not found');
  end;
  Result := DotNetRoot[RegView];
end;

function GetDotNetVersionInstallRoot(const RegView: TRegView; const Version: TDotNetBaseVersion): String;
const
  VersionStrings: array [TDotNetBaseVersion] of String = ('1.1', '2.0', '4.0', '');
var
  K: HKEY;
begin
  if DotNetVersionRoot[RegView, Version] = '' then begin
    GetDotNetInstallRoot(RegView);
    if (Version in [netbase40, netbaseHighestKnown]) and (RegOpenKeyExView(RegView, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\Policy\v4.0', 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, K) = ERROR_SUCCESS) then begin
      DotNetVersionRoot[RegView, Version] := AddBackslash(DotNetRoot[RegView]) + 'v4.0.30319';
      RegCloseKey(K);
    end else if (Version in [netbase20, netbaseHighestKnown]) and (RegOpenKeyExView(RegView, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\Policy\v2.0', 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, K) = ERROR_SUCCESS) then begin
      DotNetVersionRoot[RegView, Version] := AddBackslash(DotNetRoot[RegView]) + 'v2.0.50727';
      RegCloseKey(K);
    end else if (Version in [netbase11, netbaseHighestKnown]) and (RegOpenKeyExView(RegView, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\Policy\v1.1', 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, K) = ERROR_SUCCESS) then begin
      DotNetVersionRoot[RegView, Version] := AddBackslash(DotNetRoot[RegView]) + 'v1.1.4322';
      RegCloseKey(K);
    end;
    if DotNetVersionRoot[RegView, Version] = '' then begin
      if Version <> netbaseHighestKnown then
        InternalError(Format('.NET Framework version %s not found', [VersionStrings[Version]]))
      else
        InternalError('.NET Framework not found');
    end;
  end;
  Result := DotNetVersionRoot[RegView, Version];
end;
```

That code is in the [`DotNet.pas`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Projects/DotNet.pas) file.

---

As a resut of the above location in Inno Setup raising the error, I have asked him to use regedit and verify the existing off:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
```

---

#### Update

So he did try the install using the `/log` switch and as expected, it says:

```
2022-05-13 14:15:46.196   Fatal exception during installation process (Exception):
                          Internal error: .NET Framework not found.
2022-05-13 14:15:46.196   Exception message:
2022-05-13 14:15:46.196   Message box (OK):
                          Internal error: .NET Framework not found.
2022-05-13 14:15:53.456   User chose OK.
2022-05-13 14:15:53.456   Message box (OK):
                          Setup was not completed.
                          
                          Please correct the problem and run Setup again.
2022-05-13 14:15:59.450   User chose OK.
2022-05-13 14:15:59.450   Rolling back changes.
2022
```

I now await his response about the registry key.

---

I can confirm that in his case, whilst all the framework files etc are installed, that the cause of the internal failure is this function:

```
function GetDotNetInstallRoot(const RegView: TRegView): String;
var
  K: HKEY;
begin
  if DotNetRoot[RegView] = '' then begin
    if RegOpenKeyExView(RegView, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework', 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, K) = ERROR_SUCCESS then begin
      RegQueryStringValue(K, 'InstallRoot', DotNetRoot[RegView]);
      RegCloseKey(K);
    end;
    if DotNetRoot[RegView] = '' then
      InternalError('.NET Framework not found');
  end;
  Result := DotNetRoot[RegView];
end;
```

Here does not have the `InstallRoot` registry value.

Comment: The approach your script uses (`InstallRoot`) is long out of date. Microsoft documents the official way in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed and shouldn't be that hard for you to translate to Pascal Script as you already get examples.

Comment: @LexLi That is not my script - that is the Inno Setup script (I linked to it - `DotNet.pas`). That is, it is part of Inno itself, not my own script or anything.

Comment: Instead of relying on Inno Setup sample/built-in scripts, you can always write your own according to what Microsoft says in your own `InitializeSetup` function then.

Comment: @LexLi I get that. But all the same I am directing this ticket to Inno team too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4104011/2287576 looks promising. Seems to be the right way to do it. Testing.

Comment: Turns out that this particular issue is because my script is using the `{dotnet40}` and `{dotnet4064}` constants for using `regasm`. The user does not have the `InstallRoot` path in the registry.

Comment: See: https://groups.google.com/g/innosetup/c/u3ty6tfi4Ek